# "breadth-first-search" and "bfs" tags should be merged?

Tags: support, status-completed, tag-synonym-process

It seems to me that [breadth-first-search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/breadth-first-search) with 636 questions and [bfs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bfs) with 252 questions should be merged into [breadth-first-search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/breadth-first-search). There is a [synonym request](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/breadth-first-search/synonyms), but it doesn't have enough votes.

Comment: I’m not totally sure that *either* of these tags are particularly useful, but having two of them certainly isn’t.

Answer (score 34):

As far as I can see, [bfs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bfs) doesn't have any other meaning than [breadth-first-search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/breadth-first-search), so these should definitely be merged. You suggest keeping [breadth-first-search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/breadth-first-search) and redirecting [bfs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bfs), **I agree!**

However, if I understand the synonym request correctly, then it asks for [breadth-first-search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/breadth-first-search) being mapped to [bfs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bfs). Change it to the exact opposite, redirect all questions tagged [bfs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bfs) to [breadth-first-search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/breadth-first-search), and I'll support this suggestion!

Comment: I think it’s the other way around. `bfs` is being approved as a synonym of `breadth-first-search`, meaning `breadth-first-search` will stay.

Comment: I have no idea what directly a synonym causes the collapse to go in.  I suspect it needs to be better documented, ideally on the page where you request a synonym.

Comment: I think @JF is correct. Note that the synonym voting... thing is right above the "Suggest a synonym" box and below the description about who can vote. Nothing appears on the [tag:bfs] [synonym page](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/bfs/synonyms) about it. I would definitely not object to a more clear interface, though.

Comment: So bfs is not the Be File System?

Comment: @JF has it right. The synonym page asks you to suggest synonyms (bfs) of the master (breadth-first-search). See also http://stackoverflow.com/tags/synonyms. FWIW, I've also approved the synonym and merged bfs into breadth-first-search.

Answer (score 0):

bfs is mostly known to as breadth-first-search, but there is best-first-search as well. to my opinion, instead of merging the tags - verify and add either of the tags to another

Comment: "verify and add either of the tags to another". I don't know what this means.

Comment: In the about section of [tag:bfs] tag.It is described as `breadth-first-search` not as `best-first-search`

Comment: That's about the 'about' section of tag; but I think the point to concentrate is better reachability when searching questions/answers for something - bfs in this case